# How do I use putty in full-screen mode?

Tags: putty

I am running `putty` (August 7, 2013 build from wheezy) but don't know how to get it into full-screen mode.

In windows I used to just right-click on it in the taskbar and select Full-screen mode. In Debian I don't see that option.

I also had a look in `Window->Appearance` but couldn't see anything. Pressing `Alt+Enter` has no effect. I am using `gnome`.

Comment: Just a remark: konsole from KDE is very good as well, although in the last years I reached with gnome terminal what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused. Why are you using putty in Debian? Use a terminal in gnome or konsole in KDE. Or directly press Ctrl+Alt+F2.

I think double clicking on the heading of putty will put it to full screen mode - but I am not sure as I never used putty in linux.

Comment: he may be used to some workflow in putty from when he used it in linux

Comment: @pqnet yes. And this answer maximises the window, but doesn't make `putty` full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Short: you don't (not a feature of PuTTY).

Long: It depends. PuTTY on Linux is a *port* from Windows, and there are differences between Linux (Xorg) and Windows.  Both have three modes of *windows*:

- normal
- maximized
- minimized (iconified)

A full-screen application is no longer a window.  PuTTY is running as an *X window* application.  On Windows, it uses a special mode to take over the full screen.

There are full-screen games (and a few applications) on Linux, and those probably run in a different virtual console than X — outside the windowing system.  In principle (but a lot of work, perhaps), PuTTY's X window port could be extended to do the same thing.

With *some* window managers, you can configure a fullscreen toggle action.  That doesn't seem to be the case with Gnome3.

Your best route would be to use `wmctrl`, which can only simulate fullscreen mode by setting the `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN` property:

- use `"wmctrl -l"` to show the list of windows, because `wmctrl` uses *titles* rather than window-ids, and
- use `"wmctrl -r` *title* `-b toggle,fullscreen"` to toggle its fullscreen state.

Further reading:

- [Exclusive Fullscreen Mode](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2010-September/050951.html) (Xorg mailing list thread)
- [wmctrl - interact with a EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl)
- [Resize a Window to a Specific Size in Ubuntu](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/resize-a-window-to-a-specific-size-in-ubuntu/)
- [Is there a way to turn gvim into fullscreen mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2140/is-there-a-way-to-turn-gvim-into-fullscreen-mode) (Gnome2)
- [Can I force full screen mode for any application?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/can-i-force-full-screen-mode-for-any-application) (Elementary OS)
- [How to exit from fullscreen mode of Putty?](https://superuser.com/questions/520436/how-to-exit-from-fullscreen-mode-of-putty) (for Windows, of course)

Answer (score 0):

One valid reason for using PuTTY on Debian (and my reason) is to use ANSI printing from the host to the client printer. X Terminal, at least the implementation on an HP T520 thin client, does not support ANSI printing, but PuTTY makes it relatively easy. Not as easy as on Windows, but relatively easy.

At least on the flavor of Debian used by the HP T520 thin client, the PuTTY window can be maximized by double-clicking the title bar. This does not resize the fonts (which is optional on Windows), but it does improve user-friendliness for kiosk usage.

I find on my displays that using the font "client:Monospace 20" works well, particularly on a 4x3 display set to 1024*768 with the taskbar set to autohide. A 1600x900 display has a little extra black space around the display, which is offset to the left. Just adjust the text size to fit your displays.

And I am looking for a way to automate making the window full-screen, so it will run full-screen on system startup.